# Is there a way to use awk to count the number of rows between 2 flags and input that number into a specific field?

Tags: awk, counting, reformatting

I have a set of data that consists of seismic wave travel times and their corresponding information (i.e. source that produced the wave and the time for that wave arriving at each geophone along the spread). I am trying to format the data to fit my code in order to do some tomography using the data, but I'm still relatively new to awk. I am at a point where I need to now insert the number of receivers for each shot/source into the line of shot/source information, but its a variable amount each time. Is there a way to have awk count the number of rows and insert that into the proper field?

My data is formatted like the following.

Each line that documents a source/shot:

`s 0.01 0 0 -1 0`

Every other line that follows the source/shot information:

```
r 0.1 0 0 1.218 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.214 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.213 0.01
```

I can use the "s" as a flag for the shot lines, and I would like to count the number of "r" lines for each source/shot and insert that number into the corresponding "s" line.

The number of "r" lines for each "s" line varies greatly.

Given this sample input:

```
s 0.01 0 0 -1 0
r 0.1 0 0 1.218 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.214 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.213 0.01
s 1.01 0 0 -1 0
r 0.05 0 0 1.159 0.01
r 0.1 0 0 1.127 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.106 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.115 0.01
r 0.25 0 0 1.107 0.01
```

The expected output is:

```
s 0.01 0 3 -1 0
r 0.1 0 0 1.218 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.214 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.213 0.01
s 1.01 0 5 -1 0
r 0.05 0 0 1.159 0.01
r 0.1 0 0 1.127 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.106 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.115 0.01
r 0.25 0 0 1.107 0.01
```

Note the `3` as $4 in the first `s` line and the `5` as $4 in the second one.

The counted number of rows should be in the 4th column of each "s" line (asterisks here).

My experience with awk is limited to just rearranging/indexing columns, so I don't really know where to begin with this. I've tried googling help with awk, but it's very difficult to find answered awk questions that actually pertain to my specific situation (hence why I have decided to ask it myself).

I'm also new to using stackoverflow, so if I need to include more example data, please let me know. My data consists of approximately 4000 lines.

EDIT: The reason the desired result has slightly different data to the example of my data is because there are hundreds of lines for each "s" line and including that in the question seems excessive. I have cut out the majority of the data for ease of reading.

Comment: consider reviewing [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question; in particular, provide a sample set of input data (10-15 lines demonstrating a couple sets of s/r data), the (`awk`) code you've attempted, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: I've edited the question to include an example desired result. I have no example of what I've tried with awk because I have no idea where to start for this type of thing, as is stated in the question.

Comment: thanks for the update (sample inputs/outputs) but ... these two sets of data do not appear to match; you've provided a single `s` line and 13 `r` lines of input, but the output shows 2 `s` lines and a total of 12 `r` lines; it's not clear how you go from 1/13 to 2/12, unless this is a typo in which case it would help if you update the question to insure the inputs and outputs actually match

Comment: Good show adding your data, but is this **minimum** amount of data for readers to demonstrate your problem?  If it will work for 3-4 lines of dummied data, then it should work for any number of real lines of data. But if you need all of this OK. You want to "design" your sample data so all generic cases are covered.

Comment: But agreeing with Mark that there are still some problems. In reading your description *"and insert that number into the corresponding "s" line"* so is the `7` in your line `s 0.01 0 7 -1 0` meant to be that *count* from your sample data? Good luck.

Comment: Edited again to try and address the concerns everyone has said here. The second dataset has more information to include an example of what two "blocks" of "s" data would look like. As stated, there are hundreds of lines for each "s" line, so I have cut out data to have a minimum amount of data to work with. I know how to count lines with awk, but I'm uncertain of how to count lines between specific flags/values (if that's even possible at all). It's not necessary to insert that counted values into the original data in the same awk script, as long as I can save them to another file.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to learn how to do this with awk for ease of use in the future, but if it isn't possible, I can resort to using excel. This usually results in formatting problems with text files though when translating from windows to linux, from my experience so far. Also to reinforce: the number of "r" lines for each "s" line is variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple method is to read the file backwards.

- whenever you see an `r` line, increment a counter
- whenever you see an `s` line, substitute the counter and reset it

and then reverse the result:

```
tac input |
awk '
    /^r/ { n++ }
    /^s/ { $4=n; n=0 }
         { print }
' |
tac > output
```

You can read the file forwards but that involves maintaining state:

```
awk '
    /^s/ {
        # this prints the *previous* group of lines
        if (NR>1)
            print c1,c2,c3, n, c5,c6, r

        # save s columns, initialise n counter and r string
        c1=$1; c2=$2; c3=$3; n=0; c5=$5; c6=$6; r=""
    }
    /^r/ {
        n++
        r = r RS $0
    }
    END {
        # print final group
        print c1,c2,c3, n, c5,c6, r
    }
' input >output
```

Comment: Thank you for this response! The simple example you gave worked, and I just wanted to ask for clarification to make sure I understand the syntax of awk here. the "/^r/" is that setting r as a flag for the counter?

Comment: `/regex/` is a regex match. it is short for `$0 ~ /regex/`. In this case the regex is `^` - match start of line, `r` - match literal "r"

Comment: awk programs have form **pattern** `{` **action** `}` . **pattern** is usually an expression that can return true or false (it can also be of form **expr** `,` **expr** which matches ranges of line - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_08

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    /^s/ {
        if (NR>1) {
            prt()
        }
        cnt = 0
        shot = $0
        rs = ""
    }
    /^r/ {
        cnt++
        rs = rs $0 ORS
    }
    END { prt() }

    function prt(    orig) {
        orig = $0
        $0 = shot
        $4 = cnt+0
        print $0
        printf "%s", rs
        $0 = orig
    }
' file
s 0.01 0 3 -1 0
r 0.1 0 0 1.218 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.214 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.213 0.01
s 1.01 0 5 -1 0
r 0.05 0 0 1.159 0.01
r 0.1 0 0 1.127 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.106 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.115 0.01
r 0.25 0 0 1.107 0.01
```

Comment: @jhnc I always go back and forth between setting re-initializing variables inside a `prt()` function vs setting them in the block that calls the `prt()` function. There's pros and cons to both. In this case I decided to reset `rs` in the calling block. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yup forgot to copy/paste that line change. I agree they're very simi8lar, I mainly want to show how to avoid storing individual fields by saving/restoring `$0` in the `prt()` function. If you'd like to pull that part into your answer I'd be happy to delete mine.

Comment: yes, that annoyed me, so useful to know how to avoid

Comment: The other thing I often do is `split($0,c)` to save the fields then `print c[1], c[2], etc....` later rather than having to save separate `c` variables `c1=$1; c2=$2; ...` to use later `print c1, c2, etc....`

Answer (score 2):

Undoing the desired updates from OP's expected output gives me the following input:

```
$ cat input.dat
s 0.01 0 0 -1 0
r 0.1 0 0 1.218 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.214 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.213 0.01
s 1.01 0 0 -1 0
r 0.05 0 0 1.159 0.01
r 0.1 0 0 1.127 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.106 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.115 0.01
r 0.25 0 0 1.107 0.01
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '

function print_block(i) {
    if (s_line) {                       # if s_line not empty then ...
       sub(/COUNT/,cnt,s_line)          # replace "COUNT" with actual count and ...
       print s_line                     # print s line and ..
       for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++)
           print r_lines[i]             # r lines to stdout
    }
    cnt    = 0
    s_line = ""
    delete r_lines
}

$1 == "s" { print_block()               # print previous block of s/r lines
            $4     = "COUNT"            # replace 4th field with placeholder "COUNT"
            s_line = $0                 # save current s line
          }
$1 == "r" { r_lines[++cnt] = $0 }       # save r lines
END       { print_block() }             # flush last s/r block to stdout
' input.dat
```

This generates:

```
s 0.01 0 3 -1 0
r 0.1 0 0 1.218 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.214 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.213 0.01
s 1.01 0 5 -1 0
r 0.05 0 0 1.159 0.01
r 0.1 0 0 1.127 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.106 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.115 0.01
r 0.25 0 0 1.107 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ruby based on a multi-line regex:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.read.scan(/(^s.*\R)((?:^r.*\R?)+)/).
    map{|s,r| n=r.split(/\R/).length; a=s.split; a[3]=n; "#{a.join(" ")}\n#{r}"}' file
```

Or, reverse the lines in memory and print at the end:

```
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{lines=[]}
lines<<$F
END{
    n=0
    puts lines.reverse.
         map{|l| if l[0]=="s" then l[3]=n; n=0 else n+=1 end; l.join(" ")}.
         reverse.join("\n")
}
' file
```

Or, parse the input into rolling blocks. The advantage here is only the relevant block has to be in memory:

```
ruby -lane 'BEGIN{
    lines=[]
    def print_block(block) = puts block.map{|l| l.join(" ")}.join"\n"
}
if $F[0]=="s" then
    print_block(lines) if lines.length>0
    $F[3]=$F[3].to_i
    lines=[$F]
else
    lines[0][3]+=1
    lines<<$F
end
END{print_block(lines)}
' file
```

Or you can use this GNU awk:

```
gawk '@include "join"
function p(){
    for(i=1;i<=length(lines); i++)
        print join(lines[i],1,length(lines[i])," ")
}

/^s/{
    if (lc>1) p()
    delete lines
    lc=1
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) lines[lc][i]=$i
}
/^r/{
    lc++
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) lines[lc][i]=$i
    lines[1][4]++
}
END{p()}' file
```

Any of these prints:

```
s 0.01 0 3 -1 0
r 0.1 0 0 1.218 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.214 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.213 0.01
s 1.01 0 5 -1 0
r 0.05 0 0 1.159 0.01
r 0.1 0 0 1.127 0.01
r 0.15 0 0 1.106 0.01
r 0.2 0 0 1.115 0.01
r 0.25 0 0 1.107 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

When solving problems for myself I often have to resort to dirty techniques, such as modifying the input. Here, I'm adding a line starting with "s" at the end of the file to avoid creating an END block. If my code were simpler, having an END block would be much preferred, of course. Or, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77362417/1729388), grokking awk's function syntax would have helped me to simplify as well.

```
sed '$a\
s
' input |
awk '
BEGIN {
        delete lines[0]
}
{
        line=$0
}
($1 == "s") {
        ln=NR
        if (length(lines) > 0) {
                $0=lines[0]
                delete lines[0]
                $0=$0
                $4=length(lines)
                print
                for (i in lines) {
                        $0 = lines[i]
                        delete lines[i]
                        print
                }
        }
        lines[0]=line
}
($1 == "r") {
        lines[NR-ln]=line
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gawk` (GNU `awk`), you can use the `gensub` function as follows, leveraging awk's ability to use arbitrary strings as field and record separators ([demo](https://ideone.com/bex5jz)):

```bash
awk -v RS='s' -v FS='r' -v ORS='' -v OFS='r' \
    '{ $1 = gensub(/[0-9.-]+/, NF - 1, 3, $1) } NR != 1 { print RS $0 }' \
    input.dat
```

If the `gensub` function is not available it is a little more involved to split the `s` line and make the change, but it is still doable (see below).

The approach works as follows:

- We set the field separator (`FS`) and record separator(`RS`) to `r` and `s` respectively. This means that `awk` will read all the `s` and its `r` lines as one record, and the number of occurrences of `r`  would be the number of fields (`NF`) minus 1.
- We rely on the `gensub` function to replace the n-th occurrence of a regex match on the first field (i.e., the `s` row) and return that value. In our case, we would want to replace the third number with the count, i.e., `NF -1`.
- The final `{print}` prints out all lines since it matches all lines in the input. We skip the first row because `awk` would see an empty row in front of the first `s`, which we want to ignore.
- We need to set the output record and field separators (i.e., `ORS` and `OFS`) to the same values as they are during input so that awk does not print them out with its default values (i.e., spaces and new lines). Usually, we would set the `ORS` to `s` but this would produce a trailing `s`, and so we handle the output of the `s` in the output manually with `{ print RS`  bit and set `ORS` to empty.

---

A variation of this answer that would work even when the `gensub` function is not available is as follows ([demo](https://ideone.com/AMyp2I)):

```bash
awk -v RS='s' -v FS='r' -v ORS='' -v OFS='r' \
    'NR != 1 { 
        string = ""; 
        split($1, numbers," "); 
        
        numbers[3] = NF - 1; 
        for(i in numbers) string = string " " numbers[i]; 
        
        $1 = string "\n"; 
        print "s" $0
    }'
```

The logic remains the same, except that since we cannot use a handy regex function to do the replacement, we split the string and replace the part we need.